# Request POST modifies object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm trying to post an object with Request using post like this ->

```
function postData(data, cb) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/datastream',
        form: data,
    }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
        cb(body);
    });
}
```

And the object looks like this:

```
{
    "tblPartsReport": {
        "valid": true,
        "message": "Execute SQL: SELECT * FROM tblPartsReport WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblPartsReport); success !",
        "records": [{
            "ResourceID": 61,
            "TimeStamp": "2017-04-04T05:52:19Z",
            "PNo": 0,
            "ErrorID": 0,
            "ID": 10174
        }]
    },
    "tblMachineReport": {
        "valid": true,
        "message": "Execute SQL: SELECT * FROM tblMachineReport WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblMachineReport); success !",
        "records": [{
            "ResourceID": 61,
            "TimeStamp": "2017-04-04T05:52:19Z",
            "AutomaticMode": true,
            "ManualMode": false,
            "Busy": false,
            "Reset": false,
            "ErrorL0": false,
            "ErrorL1": false,
            "ErrorL2": false,
            "ID": 26562
        }]
    }
}
```

The object is valid and ok, but after posting it looks like this on the other side:

```
console.log(req.body);

{
    'tblMachineReport[valid]': 'true',
    'tblMachineReport[message]': 'Execute SQL: SELECT * FROM tblMachineReport WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblMachineReport); success !',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][ResourceID]': '61',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][TimeStamp]': '2017-04-04T05:52:19Z',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][AutomaticMode]': 'true',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][ManualMode]': 'false',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][Busy]': 'false',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][Reset]': 'false',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][ErrorL0]': 'false',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][ErrorL1]': 'false',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][ErrorL2]': 'false',
    'tblMachineReport[records][0][ID]': '26562',
    'tblPartsReport[valid]': 'true',
    'tblPartsReport[message]': 'Execute SQL: SELECT * FROM tblPartsReport WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblPartsReport); success !',
    'tblPartsReport[records][0][ResourceID]': '61',
    'tblPartsReport[records][0][TimeStamp]': '2017-04-04T05:52:19Z',
    'tblPartsReport[records][0][PNo]': '0',
    'tblPartsReport[records][0][ErrorID]': '0',
    'tblPartsReport[records][0][ID]': '10174'
}
```

Any idea why is this happening? I tried with Axios too but could not get the post working. I just want to post a regular object. Normally i have been using jQuery AJAX.

EDIT:
This was the correct way :)

```
function postData(data, cb) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3001/datastream',
        json: true,
        body: data,
    }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
        cb(body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use the node module request.
You have to use the json option not the form option.
Set json to true and place your data in body not in form.

> body - entity body for PATCH, POST and PUT requests. Must be a Buffer, String or ReadStream. If json is true, then body must be a JSON-serializable object.
>
> form - when passed an object or a querystring, this sets body to a querystring representation of value, and adds Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded header. When passed no options, a FormData instance is returned (and is piped to request). See "Forms" section above.

https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

The output, which you included in your post, is in the format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as far as I remember PHP and other pure server-side languages prefer this format.

Comment: Thanks guys. This was correct :) I had to use "json: true" and "body: data"